# CSS Percent Not Working Correct

Tags: javascript, html, css

The webpage has a parent container with 4 child containers. Sketch:

```
---------------
|  Child 0    |
|-------------|
|  Child 1    |
|-------------|
|  Child 2    |
|-------------|
|  Child 3    |
---------------
```

CSS

```
.Parent {
    float: right;
    height: 300px;
    width: 25%;
}
.Child {
   height: 22%;
   margin-bottom: 4%; 
}
```

Javascript

```
var pParent = document.getElementById("id");
pParent.className = "Parent";
for(var k = 0; k < 4; ++k) {
    var pChild = document.createElement("div");
    pChild.className = "Child";
    pParent.appendChild(pChild);
}
```

The 4 child containers should fit perfectly into the parent container:

4 * 22% + 3 * 4% = 100% or

4 * 22% of 300px + 3 * 4% of 300px = 300px where

4 is the number child containers and

3 is the number of spaces/margins between the child containers

But they do not. Depending on the browser size, the child containers may be much to small or even move outside of the parent container. Can anyone help me what I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: "4 * 22% + 3 * 4% = 100%" is not correct, it would be, "4 * 22% + 4* 4% = 104%".  Assign a margin of 3%

Comment: @Manoj: There is hardly no HTML, only a body and a div with id="id".

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption of "4 * 22% + 3 * 4% = 100%" is not correct, it would be, "4 * 22% + 4* 4% = 104%" because a margin-bottom would be applied for each of the children.
Try this,

```
.Parent {
    float: right;
    height: 300px;
    width: 25%;
}
.Child {
   height: 22%;
   margin-bottom: 3%; 
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to have `margin-bottom: 4%` for first three children and none for the last one  do this,

```
.Parent {
        float: right;
        height: 300px;
        width: 25%;
    }
    .Child {
       height: 22%;
       margin-bottom: 4%; 
    }
.Parent:last-child{
        height: 22%;
       margin-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this before, but it had no effect. My problem was that I did not know that the source for calculation the margin is always the parent width. So with that information the behaviour of the browser makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a combination of several mistakes:

1. Simple math - margin-bottom appears 4 times, not 3. (22+4)*4 = 104.
2. `margin-bottom: xx%` - you expect that to be a percentage of the parent height, but actually the parent width is the source for calculating the margin, even for `margin-bottom`.

Comment: Thanks Amit, I did not know that the source for calculation the margin is always the parent width. So with that information the behaviour of the browser makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`margin-bottom` is calculated against width, you might want to look at flexboxes.

Comment: Thanks Ryszard, I did not know that the source for calculation the margin is always the parent width. So with that information the behaviour of the browser makes sense.